# ImageMagick not converting grayscale to RGB

Tags: imagemagick

Trying to use ImageMagick to resize, convert images from grayscale to RGB, and from jpg to png. Using the flags to convert to RGB as per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34875248

```
convert test.jpg -colorspace sRGB -type truecolor -resize 100x100^ -gravity center -extent 100x100 test.png
```

The resize works, and the jpg to png works, but the image stays grayscale. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1):

The answer you refer to is creating a JPEG output file, and is not entirely applicable to the situation when you are creating a PNG output file - mainly because the PNG writer does some optimisations to determine the smallest file it can write. Since your image is entirely grey, it decides, not unreasonably, to write a single-channel greyscale file rather than an unnecessarily large RGB file.

If you want to override that, you can force the PNG filetype to be RGB888 with:

```
magick ...  PNG24:result.png
```

Likewise, you can force palette mode:

```
magick ...  PNG8:result.png
```

And, 16-bit per channel RGB with:

```
magick ... PNG48:result.png
```

And 16-bit per channel RGBA with:

```
magick ... PNG64:result.png
```